# Single-ticket trip in Brandenburg, Germany

Tags: tickets, germany, berlin

I recall that we once used Brandenburg tickets in a group of three people. Another time, some local German gentlemen helped us to buy two tickets to Frankfurt-Oder at Tegel Airport. Now, I am going to travel to Cottbus alone and want more clarity.

Which ticket(s) should I actually buy at TXL?

I guess that I can use the same root, bus+railroad. The airport [recommends some VBB buses](http://www.berlin-airport.de/en/travellers-txl/to-and-from/buses-and-trains/local-public-transport/index.php). I guess that I buy bus ticket again at TXL.

But where do you have the railroad ticket kiosks?

In [VBB recommendations to travel onward from TXL](http://fahrinfo.vbb.de/bin/query.exe/en?SID=A=1@O=Flughafen%20Tegel%20%28Airport%29%20%28Berlin%29@X=13292834@Y=52554067@U=86@L=009087171@B=1@V=3.9,@p=1337161063@&ZID=&timesel=depart&externalCall=yes&start=yes%22%20target=%22_blank), I find a trip with Bus X9 - Zoo Garden, followed by RE2. There are also some other alternatives, which are more twisted and last longer because they involve more transports and transitions. VBB says however that no matter which route I choose, the whole trip will cost 14.30 anyway. This is curious because bahn.com says that 14.30 is a cost of railroad alone whereas vbb/fares, according to their website, say that AB ticket within Berlin (or, I should take another for TXL-HBf/Zoo trip?) costs 2.70.

You see, I even don't know if I should go to Zoo as VBB guides says or to HBf in order to be sure that I can buy tickets at the rail station because nobody says where has railroad placed its ticket machines.

What should I choose in the ticket machine at TXL and which railroad stations do expose the ticket kiosks?

The same applies for the backward route: will I be able to buy a single ticket to TXL in Cottbus rail station?

On Berlin airport website, www.berlin-airport.de/de/_dokumente/reisende/2014-12-14-vbb-liniennetz-b-bb.pdf, we can see that there are many cities with ABC fare zones. But what is the point of that?

Can single 1-day AB ticket be used in both city centers?

What if I also want to use public transport in another Brandenburg city -- is one day AB ticket, purchased in Berlin, also active in AB zones of other Brandenburg cities?

How options are affected if DB re-enables its online ticket ordering?

Comment: (Almost?) all stations have ticket machines, and that's certainly for Berlin Zoo, which was one of the main Berlin stations (and actually the main station in the western part of the city), even if it has been downgraded following the opening of Berlin Hauptbahnhof.

Comment: VBB is the "Verkehrsverbund Berlin Brandenburg" ("Verbund" meaning something like "alliance") and comprises the companies that run busses and tubes in Berlin and the the regional offers of Deutsche Bahn (which runs both the local trains and the S-Bahn in Berlin and Brandenburg). That's why the bus  trip within Berlin is already included in your ticket to Cottbus. You can use all local trains run by Deutsche Bahn (train number prefixed with "R") but no IC/ICC.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I expect you to say `you can use not only any regional train but also any local bus, not only Berlin bus`. I just want to fill the `alliance` with actual meaning. Which tickets cover all the trip through and where can I buy them.

Comment: Any 85-95km VBB price level ticket also covers busses.  (So, e.g., bus 109 to the Ringbahn, to some kind of RE (= Regional Express) would be covered.)  Your question is really if you can buy such a ticket at TXL.  I'm not sure, but you definitely can at any S-Bahn station's machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [stated by Louis](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57863/single-ticket-trip-in-brandenburg-germany#comment118604_57863) and others in their comments, what you need to do is buy a regional ticket that takes you to Cottbus.

You can indeed buy that at TXL airport. There is a DB ticket machines available in a place called *Tegel Boulevard* according to [the TXL website](http://www.berlin-airport.de/en/travellers-txl/shops-restaurants-and-services/services/index.php). Unfortunately the [linked PDF map](http://www.berlin-airport.de/de/_dokumente/reisende/shops-gastonomie-services/txl/24.pdf) doesn't show where that is, but I am sure the information desk will know.

I did a quick search on bahn.de for *Flughafen Tevel (Airport), Berlin* to *Cottbus* on 2015-10-30 around 6pm. It says:

- take Bus X9 to Jungfernheide Bhf (S+U)
- take RE 79478 to Cottbus

It lists the price as 14.30 EUR for a single trip inside the *VBB Tarif* including the bus and the Regional Express train.